# Adding items to an array that contain a similar index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to add an item to a PHP array. The item I'm trying to add to the array may have the same index as an item which is already in the array. How can I add the item to the array without overwriting an item that shares the same index inside the array? I'd like similar indexes to turn into a 2D array.

```
//Original Array
$array = array (
            "item1" => "data1",
            "item2" => "data2",
            "item3" => "data3"
        );

//Add items to array
$array["item1"] = "data2d";
$array["item5"] = "data4";

//Desired output
array (
    "item1" => array("data1", "data4"),
    "item2" => "data2",
    "item3" => "data3",
    "item4" => "data4"
);
```

How would I achieve the desired output?

Comment: Your desired output is a multi-dimensional array, so I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: If an item is added to an array and the index already exists, I'd like the index to contain an array of the values, instead of it just being overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a function like below. The function has not been tested so there might be some syntax errors.

```
function addArray(&$array, $key, $value) {
  if (isset($array[$key])) {
    if (!is_array($array[$key])) {
      $tmp = $array[$key];
      $array[$key] = array($tmp, $value);
    }
    else {
      array_push($array[$key], $value);
    }
  }
  else {
    $array[$key] = $value;
  }      
}
```

Used like

```
$array = array (
  "item1" => "data1",
  "item2" => "data2",
  "item3" => "data3"
);

//Add items to array
addArray($array, 'item1', 'data2d');
```